# Python: preferred way to handle large number of attributes that might not exists?

Tags: python, attributes, set

EDIT:
The original problem involves PyQt and matplotlib and the real question is too complicated to explain, so I tried to simplify it and it didn't really work out. But from the replies I learned the actual problem might lie somewhere else than what I originally thought. I guess this is what learning to program is about.

Thanks everyone!

---

I'm facing a stylistic problem that bothers me. I tried to make is as general as possible to be helpful to others as well. Consider the following class:

```
class Values(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_attr = None
        self.second_attr = None
        self.third_attr = None
        self.fourth_attr = None

    def set_first(self, data):
        self.first_attr = data

    def set_second(self, data):
        self.second_attr = data

    def set_third(self, data):
        self.third_attr = data

    def set_fourth(self, data):
        self.fourth_attr = data

    def add_to_three(self):
        attrs = (
                 self.first_attr,
                 self.second_attr,
                 self.third_attr,
                 )
        self._add_one(attrs)

    def add_to_two(self):
        attrs = (
                 self.second_attr,
                 self.fourth_attr,
                 )

        self._add_one(attrs)

    def _add_one(self, attrs):
        for attr in attrs:
            if attr:
                attr += 1
```

We have a class of values. The class can have a total of 4 attributes of different values. Each value can be set with a setter (didn't use decorators to simplify things).

There are also two methods that have a tuple of attributes whose value should be increased. These values are determined before run time.

We also have a method "add_one" that adds one to those attributes that it receives if those attributes are set. Otherwise nothing should happen.

Now let's create a couple instances and set some values

```
first_values = Values()
first_values.set_second = 5

first_values.add_to_three()

second_values = Values()
second_values.set_first = 2
second_values.set_third = 4

second_values.add_to_two()
```

This works fine, because the "add_one" method checks if each attribute is set.

But what if I have 50 attributes? I don't like the idea of setting them all to None. Also, I don't like the idea of explicitly writing the tuples in those add_to_ methods.

What would be the most proper way to handle this if there are lots of attributes by changing only the Values class?

Comment: Why use setters *at all*, btw?

Comment: "But what if I have 50 attributes?" Why would you have a single class with 50 attributes? This would be a terrible smell.

Comment: Yeah, I could just remove them to make the code shorter. Valid point.

Comment: I have a really hard time understanding what you are trying to do. I feel that either you made your code generic to ask the question and it doesn't make sense, or you're overcomplicating things and should probably just be using a `list` of values and functions over it...

Comment: Johnsyweb: Well, 50 is extreme. I'm just kinda trying to find the point when to start using inheritance for example basically only because of the number of attributes.

Comment: Martin: This is indeed generic and I tried to explain the real problem that has PyQt and matplotlib involved, but it's way too long to explain and anyone to read. I guess the problem lies deeper than I might have thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should allow you to create objects with an open-ended set of attributes, including attributes that are tuples and then increment their contents.

```
class Values():
    def __init__(self, *attrs):
        '''each element in attrs is a tuple(attrname, value)'''
        if attrs is not None:
            for a in attrs:
                n, v = a
                setattr(self, n, v)

    def add_one(self, attr):
        a = getattr(self, attr, None)
        if a:
            if isinstance(a, tuple):
                setattr(self, attr, tuple(e + 1 for e in a))
            else:
                setattr(self, attr, a + 1)

v = Values(('x', 1), ('y', 2), ('z', 3), ('t', (7, 8, 9)))
print('Initial values:', v.x, v.y, v.z, v.t)
v.add_one('x')
print('X modified:', v.x, v.y, v.z, v.t)
v.add_one('t')
print('T modified:', v.x, v.y, v.z, v.t)
v.add_one('a')
print('Tried to modify non-existent attribute "a"', v.x, v.y, v.z, v.t)
```

Results:

```
>>> import attr
Initial values: 1 2 3 (7, 8, 9)
X modified: 2 2 3 (7, 8, 9)
T modified: 2 2 3 (8, 9, 10)
Tried to modify non-existent attribute "a" 2 2 3 (8, 9, 10)
>>>
```

This code will allow you to dynamically create objects with each instance containing a subset of a potentially vast number of possible attributes and manipulate the attributes of each instance.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! Somehow you picked up the idea even though my example was rather bad and didn't really give the right idea of the real problem I had. I had getattr/setattr in mind and it looks a lot more pythonic than setting to None let's say 10 attributes that might or might not be needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a dictionary

```
data = {'two': 4}
attrs = ['one','two','three']
for attr in attrs:
    if data.has_key(attr):
        data[attr] += 1
    else:
        data[attr] = 1 # this assumes all new attributes had an effective value of zero when they didn't exist
        # it seems like you want nonesxistant attributes to remain nonexistant
        # so just remove the else case
```